# Fragment View.OnClickListener does not recognize clicks

Tags: android, butterknife

My Fragment implements View.OnClickListener but does not recognize any clicks at all.

Fragment code:

```
public class StartFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @BindView(R.id.my_button)
    Button mybutton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_start, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        mybutton.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("START", "Click Detected");
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.mybutton:

        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand this behaviour, why does it not recognize any clicks? Did I miss something here?

I removed some other buttons I have in my Fragment code, along with some override methods that should not be of importance for this question.

EDIT:

Even if I try to declare my buttons as:

```
    Button myButton= view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

inside of `onCreateView` I still can't get it to recognize clicks. Trying `@OnClick(R.id.your_btn)` with ButterKnife as suggested, does not help my case either.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using ButterKnife. Try ButterKnife **@OnClick(R.id.your_btn)**.
Else find your view without **ButterKnife** and then check if it works. Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried this without any succes. Could you check my edit at the bottom of my question, please?

Comment: Hi, if you set debug break points does it get to the header of the onclick method or not even that?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is work.

```
public class StartFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@BindView(R.id.my_button)

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_start, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
   Button myButton= view.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
   myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
  }
}
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("START", "Click Detected");
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.mybutton:

    }
}
```